# Why is an "integer" data type in C++ able to hold "true" or "false; boolean values

Tags: c++, types, integer, boolean

Not much else to add, in CodeAcademy's course they use the example of

```
int hunter = true;
int anger = true;
```

And I'm just confused, based on what I just googled it doesn't say anything about integer data types in C++ holding boolean values instead of, you know, what you'd classically think of as an integer.

Noob programmer so sorry if this is an obvious one.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion _If the source type is bool, the value false is converted to zero and the value true is converted to the value one of the destination type (note that if the destination type is int, this is an integer promotion, not an integer conversion)._

Comment: A `bool` can be any type from `char` to `int` where `false = 0;` and `true = !false;`. With all compilers I've seen, `bool` is less than or equal to a 4-byte value, so it would be assignable to `int`. What value the `int` is after assignment isn't guaranteed in the `true` case across all compilers. (other than it will be non-zero).

Comment: See Integral Conversions 3rd bullet point. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_conversions

Answer (score 0):

**true** is casted to **1** and **false** is casted to **0**

```cpp
bool isCodingFun = true;
bool isFishTasty = false;
cout << isCodingFun;  // Outputs 1 (true)
cout << isFishTasty;  // Outputs 0 (false)
```

Comment: This is a bit misleading. `true` and `false` are literals of type `bool`, which is not an integer, and is distinct from `0` and `1`. Instead, there are implicit conversions between `bool` and integer. Additionally, the reason that `cout` will print `0` or `1` when passed a `bool` value is simply a formatting option. See [`std::boolalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha), which causes streams to output `"true"` and `"false"` instead.